# Why does Django call it "views.py" instead of controller?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confused by Django's claim to MVC, what is it exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291213/confused-by-djangos-claim-to-mvc-what-is-it-exactly)

Because in MVC, the "view" is usually the template...

Comment: The name `views.py` was a **MISTAKE**. [Here's the rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71664709/317522).

Answer (score 29):

#### [Django appears to be a MVC framework, but you call the Controller the “view”, and the View the “template”. How come you don’t use the standard names?](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names)

> Well, the standard names are
> debatable.
>
> In our interpretation of MVC, the
> “view” describes the data that gets
> presented to the user. It’s not
> necessarily how the data looks, but
> which data is presented. The view
> describes which data you see, not how
> you see it. It’s a subtle distinction.
>
> So, in our case, a “view” is the
> Python callback function for a
> particular URL, because that callback
> function describes which data is
> presented.
>
> Furthermore, it’s sensible to separate
> content from presentation – which is
> where templates come in. In Django, a
> “view” describes which data is
> presented, but a view normally
> delegates to a template, which
> describes how the data is presented.
>
> Where does the “controller” fit in,
> then? In Django’s case, it’s probably
> the framework itself: the machinery
> that sends a request to the
> appropriate view, according to the
> Django URL configuration.
>
> If you’re hungry for acronyms, you
> might say that Django is a “MTV”
> framework – that is, “model”,
> “template”, and “view.” That breakdown
> makes much more sense.
>
> At the end of the day, of course, it
> comes down to getting stuff done. And,
> regardless of how things are named,
> Django gets stuff done in a way that’s
> most logical to us.

Comment: ass backwards. not really debatable. lol.

Comment: This decision makes them look like amateurs. It is well known what a Controller is, and what a View is, in MVC architecture. The 'So, in our case, a "view" is the...' is a bad attempt at rationalizing a bad decision.

Comment: Well @SpaseMarkovski the 'So, in our case, a "view" is the..' describes exactly what it says, what the role of the name view in Django is and doesn't seem like an attempt for rationalizing their choice.

Comment: Even though django pattern slightly different than MVC, the word 'view' doesn't fit for whatever those functions do. imho, django should have chosen another word than 'view' to not confuse people coming from MVC. Because here functions not only render templates but also modify databases. So 'view' just sounds wrong.

Comment: @SpaseMarkovski the reason they changed the naming is because it is based on python. Python is famous for changing the naming for everything. What is the name for array in python? hint: its not named array. Django is written by python people, so renaming everything established is 'cool'.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Django is not MVC, Django prefers to call its MVC implementation MTV, for [Model Template View](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names).

See [this](http://jeffcroft.com/blog/2007/jan/11/django-and-mtv/) blog for more on Django and MTV